# How to specify -X or -e flag for maven from Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I'm trying to debug a build run through jenkins and the following error message is showing in the console log:

```
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

Is there a way to pass those flags into maven through jenkins using the jenkins GUI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends how you run maven, which is just a java program.  There are 2 scripts one for windows and one for unix/cygwin.  This can not be done with MAVEN_OPTS, you will have to change the mvn script.

1) Find where your maven is installed:

```
$ mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.3.9 (bb52d8502b132ec0a5a3f4c09453c07478323dc5; 2015-11-10T16:41:47+00:00)
Maven home: C:\opensource\apache-maven-3.3.9
Java version: 1.8.0_92, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\PROGRA~1\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\jre
Default locale: en_GB, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "amd64", family: "dos"
```

2) Add the argument for unix/cygwin in the $M2_HOME/bin/mvn at the bottom of the file (where M2_HOME is the install directory for maven):

```
exec "$JAVACMD" \
  $MAVEN_OPTS \
  $MAVEN_DEBUG_OPTS \
  -classpath "${M2_HOME}"/boot/plexus-classworlds-*.jar \
  "-Dclassworlds.conf=${M2_HOME}/bin/m2.conf" \
  "-Dmaven.home=${M2_HOME}" "-Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=${MAVEN_PROJECTBASEDIR}" \
  ${CLASSWORLDS_LAUNCHER} "$@" -X
```

3) Or for windows set the environment varibale **%MAVEN_CMD_LINE_ARGS%** which will be used in the command file mvn.cmd in $M2_HOME/bin/mvn.cmd:

```
%MAVEN_JAVA_EXE% %JVM_CONFIG_MAVEN_PROPS% %MAVEN_OPTS% %MAVEN_DEBUG_OPTS% -classpath %CLASSWORLDS_JAR% "-Dclassworlds.conf=%M2_HOME%\bin\m2.conf" "-Dmaven.home=%M2_HOME%" "-Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=%MAVEN_PROJECTBASEDIR%" %CLASSWORLDS_LAUNCHER% %MAVEN_CMD_LINE_ARGS%
```

Comment: Additionally discovered that the jenkins admin had to give ua access to the "Execute shell" parameter in the configuration screen.

Answer (score 6):

you can add `-X` to your task list , if you have `clean install` , just change it to `clean install -X`

Thanks

Comment: Useful. Thanks. I think there should really be a tickbox in Jenkins to enable the maven debug flag.